# Fields not getting updated when using 'sonata_type_model' ManyToMany mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata

Here is my TagAdmin class

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) 
    { 
        $formMapper 
            ->add('name') 
            ->add('description') 
            ->add('slug','text',array( 
                'read_only' => true, 
            )) 
            ->add('categories', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' 
=> true, 'multiple' => true)); 
    }
```

There is a `manyToMany mapping` between Categories and Tags.

I recently upgraded to Sonata Admin version 2.0.

I am sure it was working earlier, but now when I add new Categories to 
a Tag, I get a success flash message, but the change is not 
reflected.

The only other change I had made was to integrate the Chosen JQuery 
plugin for handling checkboxes. I have tried with removing that too, 
but it functions just the same.

What could be going wrong?

Here is the Tag class.

```
class Tag 
{ 
    /** 
     * @var integer $id 
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer") 
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
     */ 
    private $id; 
    /** 
     * @var string $name 
     * 
     * @Gedmo\Sluggable(slugField="slug") 
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255) 
     * @Gedmo\Translatable 
     */ 
    private $name; 
    /** 
     * @var text $description 
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text") 
     * @Gedmo\Translatable 
     */ 
    private $description; 
    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="tags") 
     */ 
    protected $categories; 
    /** 
     * @var string $slug 
     * @Gedmo\Slug(updatable=false) 
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255) 
     */ 
    private $slug; 
    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections 
\ArrayCollection(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this had nothing to do with Sonata.

It was a problem with the mapping. The Doctrine2 documentation states:

> The owning side of a relationship determines the updates to the relationship in the database.
>
> To fully understand this, remember how bidirectional associations are
>   maintained in the object world. There are 2 references on each side of
>   the association and these 2 references both represent the same
>   association but can change independently of one another. Of course, in
>   a correct application the semantics of the bidirectional association
>   are properly maintained by the application developer (that’s his
>   responsibility). Doctrine needs to know which of these two in-memory
>   references is the one that should be persisted and which not. This is
>   what the owning/inverse concept is mainly used for.
>
> Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored.
>   Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at
>   least the owning side, from Doctrine’s point of view)
>
> The owning side of a bidirectional association is the side Doctrine
>   “looks at” when determining the state of the association, and
>   consequently whether there is anything to do to update the association
>   in the database.

My mapping was defined like this:-

```
class Tag
{
...
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    protected $categories;
...
}

class Category
{
...
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="categories")
     */
    protected $tags;
...
}
```

**Setting the "inversedBy" to Tag class, solved the issue.**
So the correct implementation is this:

```
class Tag
{
...
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="tags")
     */
    protected $categories;
...
}

class Category
{
...
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    protected $tags;
...
}
```